# 2010 ford escape XLT ignition issues

Tags: ford, ignition, escape

I use to have to push my key in really hard to get it to start. 
now it wont start with the key at all. 
but if i use my remote starter to start my car then put my key in it works.
 what could this be i have see a video on you tube that i can file a piece of metal off that stop the key from turning. 
i hear a click and then nothing. i use to have to push the key in hard to get it to start and now it wont at all.
if i file it a little more its apparently suppose to fix this issue.
any ideas? 
i dont want to take it to a mechanic  i have spoke to a few and they just look at me like im stupid really want to figure this out before my remote starter fails.

Comment: sounds like maybe the rotating tab thing that goes into the switch is worn out. what happens if you unbolt the switch from the cylinder housing, put the key in the ignition and turn the switch with a screwdriver?